# Gawk cross referencing

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm having a issue with cross referencing data using gawk, when I use:

```
gawk -F: 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} $2 in a{print $1 FS a[$2]}' email.phone.txt name.email.txt > name.phone.txt
```

Example of email.phone contents:

```
Email@gmail.com:012345
Email@gmail.com:912345
```

Example of name.email.txt:

```
Charles:Email@gmail.com
Erica:Email@gmail.com
```

Expected output

```
Charles:012345
Charles:912345
Erica:012345
Erica:912345
```

However it only outputs the last matching phone using that email, so it will only output:

```
Charles:912345
Erica:912345
```

and dismiss the first phone used with that email..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU awk (`gawk`) --but **not** regular awk-- supports *true* multi-dimensional arrays, and you could use that:

```
gawk -F: '
    FNR==NR{a[$1][$2]=1;next}
    $2 in a{for(i in a[$2]) print $1 FS i}
' email.phone.txt name.email.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, fixed my issue! :)